# Randomly assign Employee Day Off within a week

Tags: c#

I have an application that will assign employee in their designated task. The problem is how can i randomly assign `day-off day` within a week for each employee. The system must work with at least 7 employees.

example:

```
Employee | Day Off
Emp 1    | Sun
Emp 2    | Wed
Emp 3    | Tue
Emp 4    | Mon
Emp 5    | Thu
Emp 6    | Sat
Emp 7    | Fri
```

But if the number of employee goes higher than the default. There must be alteast 1 day with 2 employee with `day-off`.

Example 1 with additional 1 employee

```
Employee | Day Off
Emp 1    | Sun
Emp 2    | Wed
Emp 3    | Tue
Emp 4    | Mon
Emp 5    | Thu
Emp 6    | Sat
Emp 7    | Fri
Emp 8    | Tue
```

Example 2 with additional 2 employees

```
Employee | Day Off
Emp 1    | Tue
Emp 2    | Thu
Emp 3    | Sun
Emp 4    | Mon
Emp 5    | Wed
Emp 6    | Fri
Emp 7    | Sat
Emp 8    | Tue
Emp 9    | Sun
```

Example 3 with additional 3 employees

```
Employee | Day Off
Emp 1    | Thu
Emp 2    | Sat
Emp 3    | Fri
Emp 4    | Mon
Emp 5    | Sun
Emp 6    | Wed
Emp 7    | Tue
Emp 8    | Tue
Emp 9    | Sun
Emp 10   | Wed
```

And so on..

I want the system to generate this randomly. Is there any code algorithm that will resolve this problem? thanks!

> Update

This is what i tried.

```
// Note that getActiveEmployee() returns List<Employee> object.
List<Employee> activeEmployees = this.GetActiveEmployees(); 

List<Employee> assignedEmployees = new List<Employee>();

// Set collection of employee which has no day off 
// from active employee list.
List<Employee> hasNoOffEmployees = new List<Employee>();
hasNoOffEmployees = activeEmployees; 

//  7 Days a week.
// Assumption: Start DayofWeek is sunday.
for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
{
     // Get random employee from hasNoOffEmployees.
     int eidx = rnd.Next(hasNoOffEmployees.Count);
     Employee selEmpHasOff = hasNoOffEmployees[eidx];

     foreach (Employee employee in activeEmployees)
     {
          if (selEmpHasOff == employee)
          {
               assignedEmployees.Add(employee);
               hasNoOffEmployees.Remove(selEmpHasOff);
               break;
          }
     }
}
```

The given result of `day-off` will always be like this.

Examples:

A - with 7 actual employees

```
Employee | Day Off
Emp 2    | Sun
Emp 4    | Mon
Emp 3    | Tue
Emp 1    | Wed
Emp 7    | Thu
Emp 6    | Fri
Emp 5    | Sat
```

B - with 8 actual employees.

```
Employee | Day Off
Emp 7    | Sun
Emp 6    | Mon
Emp 5    | Tue
Emp 4    | Wed
Emp 3    | Thu
Emp 8    | Fri
Emp 2    | Sat
```

C - with 9 actual employees.

```
Employee | Day Off
Emp 8    | Sun
Emp 3    | Mon
Emp 9    | Tue
Emp 4    | Wed
Emp 6    | Thu
Emp 7    | Fri
Emp 2    | Sat
```

And so on...

There is always a missing employee/s.

Comment: @Thomas i just updated the thread.

Comment: Nice. What's the `||` in `hasNoOffEmployees.Remove(selEmpHasOff); ||` ?

Comment: oh just a mistake it is the same output if i remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure you have an as evenly as possible random distribution of days off, you could do something like:

```
public enum DayOfWeek { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday };

public class Employee
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOff;
}

public class DayOffAllocator
{
    Random _random = new Random();
    DayOfWeek[] _daysOff = (DayOfWeek[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));
    List<DayOfWeek> _availableDaysOff = new List<DayOfWeek>();

    public void AllocateDayOff(Employee employee)
    {
        if (!_availableDaysOff.Any())
            _availableDaysOff = new List<DayOfWeek>(_daysOff);
        int index = _random.Next(_availableDaysOff.Count);
        employee.DayOff = _availableDaysOff[index];
        _availableDaysOff.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

You can then use this in the following manner:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee[] employees = new Employee[123]
            .Select(employee => new Employee()).ToArray();

        DayOffAllocator dayOffAllocator = new DayOffAllocator();
        foreach(var employee in employees)
        {
            dayOffAllocator.AllocateDayOff(employee);
        }
        Dictionary<DayOfWeek, int> dist = ((DayOfWeek[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
            .ToDictionary(k => k, v => employees.Count(x => x.DayOff == v));
    }
}
```

You will note that the distribution shown in `dist` is as even as possible for the example 123 employees - 3 random days will have 17 employees have that day off and the remaining 4 random days will have 18 employees have that day off.

Comment: Hey this one got a perfect result!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to randomly assign a day of to your employees. Assuming that this could be a simplified version of your class `Employee`:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek dayOff { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm " + Name + " and I don't work on " + dayOff;
    }
}
```

This code will do the job perfectly:

```
List<Employee> myWorkers = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee {Name = "Mary"},
    new Employee {Name = "Chris"},
    new Employee {Name = "Peter"},
    new Employee {Name = "John"},
    new Employee {Name = "Xavier"},
    new Employee {Name = "Matt"},
    new Employee {Name = "Oscar"},
    new Employee {Name = "Jules"},
    new Employee {Name = "Sarah"},
    new Employee {Name = "Cola"},
    new Employee {Name = "Donald"},
    new Employee {Name = "Mick"},
    new Employee {Name = "Jack"},
    new Employee {Name = "Thomas"}
};

Random r = new Random();

foreach (Employee employee in myWorkers)
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    employee.dayOff = (DayOfWeek) r.Next(7);
}
foreach (Employee employee in myWorkers)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(employee.ToString());
}
```

Which output (yours and mine will not be the same: it's random):

> I'm Mary and I don't work on Saturday
>
> I'm Chris and I don't work on Thursday
>
> I'm Peter and I don't work on Tuesday
>
> I'm John and I don't work on Tuesday
>
> I'm Xavier and I don't work on Wednesday
>
> I'm Matt and I don't work on Sunday
>
> I'm Oscar and I don't work on Wednesday
>
> I'm Jules and I don't work on Friday
>
> I'm Sarah and I don't work on Saturday
>
> I'm Cola and I don't work on Friday
>
> I'm Donald and I don't work on Saturday
>
> I'm Mick and I don't work on Friday
>
> I'm Jack and I don't work on Monday
>
> I'm Thomas and I don't work on Wednesday

But you can note that, over 14 employees:

- Saturday 21,43%
- Thursday 7,14%
- Tuesday 14,29%
- Wednesday 21,43%
- Sunday 7,14%
- Friday 21,43%
- Monday 7,14%

This is not equally spread. What I would recommand then is:

```
int i = 0;
// Easy suffle of the list, random enough for this usage
foreach (Employee employee in myWorkers.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()))
{
    employee.dayOff = (DayOfWeek) ((i++)%7);
}
```

Which will provide this spread:

- Tuesday 14,29%
- Sunday 14,29%
- Thursday 14,29%
- Monday 14,29%
- Friday 14,29%
- Saturday 14,29%
- Wednesday 14,29%

---

The issue of your code is that you were expecting to browse the 7 days of the week in your loop `for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)` but as you where just checking for the 7 first employees of the list with this code:

```
int eidx = rnd.Next(hasNoOffEmployees.Count);
Employee selEmpHasOff = hasNoOffEmployees[eidx];

foreach (Employee employee in activeEmployees)
{
    if (selEmpHasOff == employee)
    {
       assignedEmployees.Add(employee);
       hasNoOffEmployees.Remove(selEmpHasOff);
       break;
    }
}
```

That's why you didn't get it working for more than 7 people in your list.

Comment: Yes, I would like to assign a random `day-off` to every employee. Your answer was right but it does yield undesirable result. Every random 8th employee is classified as sunday `day-off` employee and the 9th as monday and so on what i'd like to be is that the 8th employee could be on tuesday or etc and so on the 9th.. but i did it using your answer by sublisting the list into 7 items. then loop again back to 7 in order to generate all random result dayofweek `day-off` for each employee.

Comment: Yeah that is why but i get the perfect result with using your approach by sublisting the list item to 7 and loop it again to random generation of `DayOfWeek`

Comment: @Roelzkie Since the employee list is shuffled, it *is* random

Comment: the employee is randomly generated but the day-off is repeated not randomly.

your result will always yield as this, Sun - Mon - Tue - Wed - Thu - Fri - Sat - then the extra 8th employee will always have a Sun `day-off`

But according to the answer of @TVOHM

The result yield this Sun - Mon - Tue - Wed - Thu - Fri - Sat then the 8th employee could start on Wed or etc.

Comment: @Roelzkie you agree that the employee & dayOff could be a key/value pair, right? Then shuffling the key before assign is the same as assign a random value